# Bash: Calculate how long it takes a script to run

Tags: bash

Is there a way to have a bash script to print how long it took to run?

Something fairly simple like:

```
#!/bin/bash
something to start time
command to be run
something to calculate runtime and print result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in other answers - time is the best for the whole script.

On the other hand if you want to caluculate length of only part of the script try to use this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
T="$(date +%s)"

sleep 2

T="$(($(date +%s)-T))"
echo "It took ${T} seconds!"
```

This simply takes some date in

> seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC        (for more see `man date`)

One before execution, one after and subtracts one from the other.

You can experiment with it a little bit to achieve better accuracy.

Answer (score 5):

There is the standard tool [`time`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time).

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo start
sleep 2
echo end
```

Usage:

```
$ time ./so.sh       
start
end
./so.sh  0.00s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 2.007 total
```

Comment: I appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [time](http://linux.die.net/man/1/time) command:

> time - run programs and summarize system resource usage

For example:

`time <command>`

Will give you the execution time of your commands

Comment: Thanks for the general info.